# Why is the Dependency Property not returning its value?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I have a MyUserControl with the following Xaml:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding InputValueProperty}" />
```

In the MyUserControl.xaml.cs I have:

```
public string InputValue
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(InputValueProperty); }
    set { SetValue(InputValueProperty, value); }
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty InputValueProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.Register("InputValueProperty", typeof(string), 
    typeof(MyUserControl));
```

In my MainWindow.xaml I create a user control:

```
<local:MyUserControl InputValue="My Input" />
```

Later on in my MainWindow.xaml.cs I am trying to access this string.  All instances of MyUserControl are contained in a List and I access them with a foreach.

```
string temp = userControl.InputValue;
```

This is always null.  In my MainWindow.xaml I can see the "My Input" in the text box of the user control but I can't ever seem to get it out of there.

Comment: I think you need to change `DependencyProperty.Register("InputValueProperty", typeof(string), 
    typeof(MyUserControl));` to `DependencyProperty.Register("InputValue", typeof(string), 
    typeof(MyUserControl));`

Comment: Yeah.  Sorry.  That was a typo.  That is set Correctly.

Comment: Where are you iterating over the userControls? in the constructor of MainWindow?...show us that code...and where. You need to wait till the MainWindow is Loaded (maybe after the UserControl is Loaded too). Also, show us how are you populating this "list" with your MyUserControl(s).

Comment: What is null, the usercontrol or the InputValue property?

Comment: The InputValue property is null.  If you default the property to something it is always that default.  It is never changing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged on your class that has the property

```
    public class YourClassThatHasTheInputValuePropertyInIt: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
            private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
            {
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }

            public string InputValue
            {
                get { return (string)GetValue(InputValueProperty); }
                set { SetValue(InputValueProperty, value);
                      NotifyPropertyChanged("InputValue"); }
     }
    }
```

This will allow the binding to pick up the property

Comment: This has nothing to do with INotifyPropertyChanged. He is talking about  binding involving only dependency properties and constant values.

Comment: INotifyPropertyChanged is merely an alternative to DependencyObject (which is his approach).  It is not a requirement.

Answer (score 4):

```
DependencyProperty.Register("InputValueProperty", ...
```

That should be:

```
DependencyProperty.Register("InputValue", ...
```

XAML depends on the registered name of the property, not the name of the property accessor.

Comment: if unsure how to implement the dependency property the visual studio snippet (type propdp then press tab twice) is always safe and fast.

Comment: Yeah.  I had this set correctly.  I typed it wrong when inputting the questions.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is in your binding.  Here's a working example that's modeled off your code with a relative source binding:

Here's the user control:

```
  public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
  {
    public MyUserControl()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string InputValue
    {
      get { return (string)GetValue(InputValueProperty); }
      set { SetValue(InputValueProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty InputValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("InputValueProperty", typeof(string),
        typeof(MyUserControl));
  }
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication4.MyUserControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication4" Height="30" Width="300">
    <Grid>
       <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=InputValue, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:MyUserControl}}}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And here's the window:

```
  public partial class Window1 : Window
  {
    public Window1()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      string text1 = ctrl1.InputValue;
      string text2 = ctrl2.InputValue;
      string text3 = ctrl3.InputValue;
//breakpoint here
    }
  }

<Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication4" Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
    <StackPanel>
      <local:MyUserControl x:Name="ctrl1" InputValue="My Input" />
      <local:MyUserControl x:Name="ctrl2" InputValue="2" />
      <local:MyUserControl x:Name="ctrl3" InputValue="3" />
      <Button Click="Button_Click" Height="25" Content="debug"/>
      </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

If i throw a breakpoint in the click event i can see the bound values of each of the controls.  (if you copy and paste from this be sure to change WpfApplication4 to whatever your project is called.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I took a closer look and think i know what's wrong. I'll edit my answer.  Please look it over and accept if it works out for you.